How to read UEFI firmware data from the LINUX kernel?
My task is as follows: It is necessary to read all UEFI firmware data from the BIOS chip.
How can this be done (what is the memory area of the UEFI firmware, and is it possible to read the UEFI firmware from the Linux kernel)?

/proc/iomem lists System ROM which probably can be read but I'm far from sure.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov that only gives access to the 64KiB mapped in for compatibility reasons, not the whole ROM.

To read all firmware data directly, like the entire firmware binary this is hardly possible nowadays due to protection mechanisms on modern systems.
System ROM addresses in /proc/iomem can indicate where the firmware is located, but direct access to this memory area /dev/mem is often blocked by the kernel for security reasons.
A hardware programmer could directly read the firmware from the chip with physical access and specialized hardware.
You can try to read the files in /sys/firmware/efi/efi/, UEFI runtime services provide files in /sys/firmware/efi/efi/ that offer some metadata, though this isn’t the entire firmware.
Check for efivarfs
The UEFI variables are accessible on Linux through the efivarfs filesystem, typically mounted at /sys/firmware/efi/efivars, so you can try reading UEFI variables from here.
ls /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
efivarfs - a (U)EFI variable filesystem
efi variable entries in /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/
This doesn’t provide direct access to the entire firmware binary but to specific UEFI variables.
Also check out fwupd
fwupdmgr get-devices
arch - fwupd
There’s a lot one can try, but it’s not possible to access all information on new systems without specialized hardware and software.
Access to the Specs and Tools
Unified Extensible Firmware Interface
How to Access UEFI Settings in Linux Systems
UEFI Debian Wiki
Accessing UEFI hardware info from Linux
This is not a guide and is for informational purposes only!
For example, we had a Lenovo laptop where we forgot the BIOS/UEFI password. We were able to update the firmware on the laptop and boot Linux to view parts of the BIOS/UEFI.
However, the area containing the password was separate from the other information and couldn't be read out with linux, so we used hardware on the chip with this device, CH341 24 25 Series EEPROM Flasher USB BIOS, SOIC8 Clip On-Board to read the data directly and other details and reset the chip.

in this case, as I understand it, in order to read UEFI firmware data from a chip, it is programmatically necessary to develop something similar to the UEFI shell and read data from the chip from it (that is, not from the operating system - ring 0 level, but to a level lower - ring -1)

Read UEFI firmware data directly from the chip without restrictions, access is required that goes beyond what is normally available at the operating system level (Ring 0).
To bypass/hack this, you need to operate at a lower level, such as Ring -1, which is the operating system. There are protection mechanisms to prevent access to UEFI firmware data for security reasons. Bypassing/Hacking these mechanisms can carry certain risks.
As mentioned, you need specific hardware, software and knowledge combination, and this could also damage or destroy the chip.
"checksum to prevent an attacker" | Maybe you should ask that specifically here security.stackexchange.com you have the best options for it on the Stack Exchange networks and the best answers/help in this area for security

On many systems you can read the onboard flash ROM using flashrom, without any specialised hardware. Install it then run
sudo flashrom -p internal

to see whether your hardware is supported, and
sudo flashrom -p internal -r backup.rom

to read your system’s ROM.
You may run into issues accessing /dev/mem; see What can I do about /dev/mem errors? for help resolving those. Note that unloading the lpc_ich module will trigger your system’s watchdog if it’s equipped with one and it’s enabled; if that is the case, your system will reboot, but nothing untoward will happen other than that (assuming you don’t have unsaved data you care about at the time).
Some of the ROM may also be protected by the Management Engine (on Intel systems), but usually that’s only the ME-specific part; that may or may not be a concern for you depending on your exact requirements.
